# Generate classes from XSD removing namespaces references

Tags: java, xml, xsd, namespaces, cxf

I have a fairly large set of XSD files. From this I correctly generate Java classes (I'm using the `org.apache.cxf.cxf-xjc-plugin`). My problem is that the responses I get from the web service do not use namespaces (and obviously I have no way to ask the service provider to change the response). As a result my unmarhalling step with jaxb fails to populate internal object fields.

The code I'm using to do the unmarshal is (similar to) this:

```
    private <T> T unmarshalFromStr(String str, Class<T> clazz) throws JAXBException {
        jaxbCtx = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyGneratedClass1.class, MyGneratedClass2.class, ...);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbCtx.createUnmarshaller();
        JAXBElement<T> obj = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new StringReader(str)), clazz);
        return obj.getValue();
    }
```

I (obviously) wouldn't like to rewrite the xsd files or to manually modified the generated classes.

Any hints?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will entirely serve your purpose but you can try using a binding file to customize your JAXB classes creation and use your own package references.
For documentation check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html) out and some examples [here](https://coderleaf.wordpress.com/2016/11/15/jaxb-bindings-by-example/)